# django filter on APIView

Tags: python, django, django-rest-framework, django-filter

I have a APIView class for showing all the rents and posting and delete etc. Now i want search feature so i tried to use DjangoFilterBackend but it is not working. I see in documentation, it has been used with ListAPIView but how can i use it in APIView.

```
class Rent(APIView):
    """
    List all the rents if token is not provided else a token specific rent
    """
    serializer_class = RentSerializer
    filter_backends = (DjangoFilterBackend,)
    filter_fields = ('city', 'place', 'property_category',)
    search_fields = ('=city', '=place')
    def get(self, request, token=None, format=None):
        reply={}
        try:
            rents = Rental.objects.all()
            if token:
                rent = Rental.objects.get(token=token)
                reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(rent).data
            else:
                reply['data'] = self.serializer_class(rents, many=True).data
        except Rental.DoesNotExist:
            return error.RequestedResourceNotFound().as_response()
        except:
            return error.UnknownError().as_response()
        else:
            return Response(reply, status.HTTP_200_OK)
```

when i search the rent with the following parameters in the url, i get all the rents, instead i should get only those rents that lies in city Kathmandu and place koteshwor

http://localhost:8000/api/v1/rents?city=Kathmandu&place=Koteshwor

Comment: Since the purpose of this view appears to be to return a list of objects, why not just use a `ListAPIView`?

Comment: I have done a post, update, delete everything on this view and also to show a single rent or all the rent has been done with a single get function instead of doing ListAPIView and RetrieveAPIView

Comment: So you've replicated the functionality of a DRF Viewset.

Comment: I believe filters work only for `ViewSet`s. Since you're writing everything by hand using `APIView` you must implement filtering by hand. BTW, what do you think `DjangoFilterBackend` will do and how it fill magically filter for you when you're generating `QuerySet` manually and return JSON response?

You need to read DRF docs carefully, they have an excellent tutorial with every nuance explained.

Comment: @EugeneMorozov, the docs show filters working with a `ListAPIView` as op says. http://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/filtering/#djangofilterbackend

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Here If you are using `APIView`, There is nothing to do with filters.So you have to do like

```
get_data = request.query_params #or request.GET check both
```

Then

```
Rental.objects.filter(city=get_data['city'], place=get_data['place'])
```

Comment: If you are using `ListAPIView`, for filtering, `drf` is using this django ORM approach only anyways.

Comment: The reason i am favoring APIView is we have to do everything by hand. This will help me to learn the concept more and more. I got with the way you showed me. Thanks for your help. One more question, do you know about setup_eager_loading in rest_framework?

Comment: what if the filters are all optional?

Answer (score 16):

To use the functionality of DjangoFilterBackend, you could incorporate the `filter_queryset` method from `GenericViewSet`, which is the DRF class that inherits from `APIView` and leads to all specific 'generic' view classes in DRF. It looks like this:

```
def filter_queryset(self, queryset):
    """
    Given a queryset, filter it with whichever filter backend is in use.
    You are unlikely to want to override this method, although you may need
    to call it either from a list view, or from a custom `get_object`
    method if you want to apply the configured filtering backend to the
    default queryset.
    """
    for backend in list(self.filter_backends):
        queryset = backend().filter_queryset(self.request, queryset, self)
    return queryset
```

https://github.com/encode/django-rest-framework/blob/master/rest_framework/generics.py

Comment: This should be the accepted answer. It minimizes the amount of overhead required to achieve the desired result.

Answer (score 8):

In case someone is wondering how can we integrate `django_filters` `filter_class` with api_views:

```
@api_view(['GET'])
@permission_classes([permissions.IsAuthenticated])
def filter_data(request, format=None):
    qs = models.YourModal.objects.all()

    filtered_data = filters.YourFilter(request.GET, queryset=qs)
    filtered_qs = filtered_data.qs
    ....
    return response.Ok(yourData)
```

Comment: Besides calling qs on your filtered_data, you can call is_valid() and errors for validation:
https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/blob/master/django_filters/filterset.py

Answer (score 3):

Adding to @ChidG's answer. All you need to do is override the DjangoFilterBackend's filter_queryset method, which is the entry point for the filter, and pass it the instance of your APIView. The important point to note here is you must declare `filter_fields` or `filter_class` on the view in order to get the filter to work. Otherwise it just return your queryset unfiltered.

If you're more curious about how this works, the class is located at `django_filters.rest_framework.backends.py`

In this example, the url would look something like `{base_url}/foo?is_active=true`

```
from django_filters.rest_framework import DjangoFilterBackend

class FooFilter(DjangoFilterBackend):

    def filter_queryset(self, request, queryset, view):
        filter_class = self.get_filter_class(view, queryset)

        if filter_class:
            return filter_class(request.query_params, queryset=queryset, request=request).qs
        return queryset

class Foo(APIView):

    permission_classes = (AllowAny,)
    filter_fields = ('name', 'is_active')

    def get(self, request, format=None):
        queryset = Foo.objects.all()

        ff = FooFilter()
        filtered_queryset = ff.filter_queryset(request, queryset, self)

        if filtered_queryset.exists():
            serializer = FooSerializer(queryset, many=True)
            return Response(serializer.data, status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
        else:
            return Response([], status=status.HTTP_200_OK)
```